# Set custom, non-standard aspect ratio in Movie Maker

Tags: windows, aspect-ratio, windows-movie-maker

I am trying to edit video which has a non-standard aspect ratio. In the project settings for Movie Maker I can only see two aspect ratio options:

- Standard (4:3)
- Widescreen (16:9)

Even if I set the frame width and height to a non-standard ratio with a custom save setting, it creates black bars to fill out the video to the project's aspect ratio.

Is there a way to create a custom aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately no way to set a custom aspect ratio.